# creating T at runtime using strings and not losing intellisense

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a client/server application where the client requests some data from server. To do so, the client side sends a data request with the object name he want to gather data from. This is done using Ajax strings.

In the server side, I have a generic `DataManager<T>` class that get data from database and return the listed data, as follows:

```
public class DataManager<T> where T : class, new()
{
    public List<T> DataManager<T>
    {
         .... Get list for object T in database using reflection and return the T objects...
    }
}
```

So, my server code has the following structure to handle client requests:

```
public class Server
{
    public static object GetData(string dataObjectName)
    {
         switch (dataObjectName)
         {
             case "ObjA": 
                var objAManager = new DataManager<ObjA>();
                return objAManager.List();
                break;

             case "ObjB": 
                var objBManager = new DataManager<ObjB>();
                return objBManager.List();
                break;

             default:
                return null;
          }
    }
}
```

Today I have 2 problems:

a) As  I have different `DataManager` classes and dozens of `Objs`, my code is getting a mess of switches and testing conditions.

b) As server returns object, this is also a nightmare, as later in server script I need to do some consistences and I have no intellisense to help.

I would like to use some trick to solve that, but I don´t know where to go. I tried reflection, but to do so I´m still losing intellisense.

Any standard/method/practice or pattern to help me with that ?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just define server as:

```
 //IDataObject is an interface to provide a common contract for all entities used
 public static object GetData<T>()
   where T: IDataObject
 {
     var mgr = new DataManager<T>();
     return mgr.List();
 }
```

Sounds like the better solution would be to implement a design pattern, like the builder pattern; a director finds the correct builder object (which is an object to create the DataManager instance.  Or, find a way to commonize all of the data managers, and centralize that logic.

The tricky part is I don't know everything DataManager does, so I can't advise further.  Why all the differences in type would be the determining factor.

Comment: DataManager goes to the database, finds the table associated with its name, maps table data with object properties, and so on... A lot of 'algorithimic' work...

Comment: `Method<T as SomeType>` is not valid C# syntax

Comment: Thanks, I've been stuck in a VB world at work :-)  Fixed